Angular 18 ERROR: NG05105 with animations
Hello there I am new to angular and was trying to get animations to work but I am getting the following error "NG05105" below will be app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LeaderboardComponent } from './leaderboard/leaderboard.component';
import { TeamsComponent } from './teams/teams.component';
import { DriversComponent } from './drivers/drivers.component';
import { MatchesComponent } from './matches/matches.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LeaderboardComponent,
    TeamsComponent,
    DriversComponent,
    MatchesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

I don't know why this is happening according to the documention this should be correct blow is my @Component for where I am using the animations
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      transition(':enter', [ // alias for 'void => *'
        style({ backgroundColor: 'yellow', opacity: 0 }),
        animate('2000ms', style({ backgroundColor: 'white', opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})

and below is the HTML file
<div class="home-container">
  <h1 @fade>Welcome to the Racing League</h1>
  <p @fade>Keep track of your favorite teams, drivers, and matches.</p>
  <button @fade routerLink="/leaderboard" class="home-button">View Leaderboard</button>
</div>

I tried to make a new project thought maybe I messed something up but still the same issue, whats supposed to happen is that its supposed to change bacground color to yellow and opacity to 0 and then in a 2 second duration its supposed to turn background color to white and opacity to 1, I have no clue and any help would be greatly appreciated

issue is arising from somewhere else, please find stackblitz where it wokrs fine! please replicate the issue here and share back!

hey @NarenMurali I have tried to copy your code into VS code but it doesn't seem to be working in my local directory

I fixed the issue by changing the app.config.ts to the following:
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideAnimations()]
}


No need to use ngModule, because it is not necessary in angular 18.In app.config.ts file import provideAnimation
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideAnimations()]
}

